# Logic to choose a data point from a pool of data points based on two criteria.

Tags: probability, data-analysis

My data points can be expressed in a vector form as:

$X = [x(1), x(2), x(3), ..........,x(N)]$

Each element of $X$ has two criteria/characteristics, $P$ and $H$. $P$ is the posterior probability (probability of choosing any elements of $X$, calculated based on some input data) and $H$ is a scalar value (also calculated from the input data). In my system, a larger value of $P$ and a smaller value of $H$ is preferred for the best selection of data point. I want to combine $P$ and $H$ using any mathematical model such that I can have a good data point selection and have a good theoretical explanation.

What kind of mathematical model or filter can I use in my case?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to think about the relative importance of $H$ and $P$.  You could select the highest $P$ and use $H$ to break ties.  You could select the lowest $H$ and use $P$ to break ties.  You could compute $aP-bH$ and use that for ranking for some selection of positive number $a,b$.  There are more complicated things you can do as well.  Once you decide what your priorities are (assuming they are consistent), there will be a formula for it, but we can't guess what formula fits your priorities.

Comment: I got a good result computing `(P-H)/(P+H)` and ranking the resultant in descending order. However, I'm afraid if it is mathematically correct to use probability value with another scalar value. Is there any name for it? For eg, any correlation coefficient. Is there any mathematical theory or relation to define my approach?

Comment: As long as $P$ and $H$ have the same units the calculation makes sense and you get a unitless value.  I don't know a name for this formula, but that is no problem.  Dividing by $P+H$ will raise the value of cases where $P,H$ are small, so $P=0.01,H=0.005$ will come out ahead of $P=0.1,H=0.06$.  Is that what you want?

Comment: `P` is a probability and `H` is unitless quantity. In my case, when `P` is high, `H` gets reduced and when `P` is low, `H` is high. In this situation, is my approach correct?